# Group by close date ranges and keep original dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

With the dataframe below:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
#score    start         end        length
[1379, '2018-08-20', '2021-08-16',  156],
[1374, '2018-06-25', '2021-08-23',  165],
[1374, '2018-07-02', '2021-08-23',  164],
[1343, '2018-07-30', '2021-08-23',  160],
[1342, '2019-06-03', '2021-08-16',  115],
[1342, '2019-06-10', '2021-08-16',  114],
[1333, '2018-07-09', '2021-08-23',  163],
[1329, '2018-08-06', '2021-08-23',  159],
[1326, '2018-07-23', '2021-08-23',  161],
[1316, '2018-06-25', '2021-08-16',  164],
[1316, '2018-07-02', '2021-08-16',  163],
[1316, '2018-07-09', '2021-08-16',  162],
[1316, '2018-08-27', '2021-08-16',  155],
[1311, '2018-09-03', '2021-07-12',  149],
[1311, '2018-09-03', '2021-07-19',  150],
[1308, '2018-08-20', '2021-08-02',  154],
[1308, '2018-08-20', '2021-08-09',  155],
[1308, '2018-08-20', '2021-08-23',  157],
[1297, '2019-08-12', '2021-08-23',  106],
[1296, '2018-09-17', '2021-08-09',  151]
], columns=['score', 'start', 'end', 'length'])
```

I want to group the dates in both **start** and **end** columns such as within either **start** or **end** column, the dates which are < 2 months apart are merged in order to find the max score of each group and keep the original columns intact.

I tried the following approach:

```py
df["start"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
df["end"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
temp_df = df.copy()
temp_df = (
    temp_df
    .groupby([pd.Grouper(key='start', freq='2M'), pd.Grouper(key='end', freq='2M')])['score']
    .max()
    .reset_index()
)
temp_df
```

and obtained the following result:

[image]

We lost the **length** column and the **start** and **end** dates were not accurate, for example we did not have **2018-08-31** in **start** column before.

Could you show me a way to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: This is often a harder problem than expected. What is the reference for the 2 months? Is it the smaller one? Or will you try and find the way to group your entries to form the largest groups? I.e: what will you do if you have entries for `month`, `month+1`, `month+2` and `month+3`? And if you have `month`, `month+1.99`, `month+2`, `month+2.1`, and `month+2.2`?

Comment: @GregoirePelegrin we could omit the days, just between months would do (like as long as we are in July, going to September would always = 2 months). But in the end I wanna keep the resulting dates the same as in the orginal (not shifted)

Comment: Even though not taking into account the days makes the second part useless (but only because you decided to settle on a 2 months period, if it was more than 2 months, the problem would come back), you haven't answered the first question. What do you want to do in the case `march`, `april`, `may`, `june`?

Comment: @GregoirePelegrin I'm not sure if this helps but I'm doing a price pattern recognition task on a weekly timeframe, each row is a price pattern with start and end dates. After running through every time window I got many price patterns that are close to each other so I want to reduce their total amount by grouping them.

Answer (score 0):

After a while this was the solution I came up with, which might have been a bit lengthy but worked nevertheless:

```
while True:
    start_length = len(temp_df.index)

    """ Compute Difference From First Date In Days """
    temp_df[['diff_from_first_row_start', 'diff_from_first_row_end']] = temp_df[['start', 'end']].rsub(temp_df[['start', 'end']].iloc[0])
    temp_df['diff_from_first_row_start'] = abs(temp_df['diff_from_first_row_start'].dt.days) // 30
    temp_df['diff_from_first_row_end'] = abs(temp_df['diff_from_first_row_end'].dt.days) // 30

    """ Remaining Rows After Applying Condition """
    remain_df = temp_df[~((temp_df['diff_from_first_row_start'] < 2) & (temp_df['diff_from_first_row_end'] < 2))]

   """ Selecting Rows By Condition """
    cond_df = temp_df[(temp_df['diff_from_first_row_start'] < 2) & (temp_df['diff_from_first_row_end'] < 2)]

    """ Select Only 1 Row With Max Value """
    cond_df = cond_df[cond_df.score == cond_df.score.max()].head(1)

    """ Merge Resulting Rows From Condition And Non-Condition Rows """
    temp_df = pd.concat([remain_df, cond_df], axis=0)
    temp_df[['score', 'start', 'end', 'length']].sort_values(['start', 'end'], ascending=[0,0])

    """ Stop When There Is No More Change """
    end_length = len(temp_df.index)
    if start_length == end_length:
        break

temp_df[['score', 'start', 'end', 'length']].sort_values(['start', 'end'], ascending=[0,0])
```

The end result being:

[image]